# how to give border and border-radius to stacklayout in nativescript

Tags: css, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm new to nativescript.I don't know how to give border and border-radius to stacklayout.

Below I have posted what I tried so far:

**component.html:**

```
 <StackLayout class ="stackBorder" orientation="horizontal">
    <Label text="Label 1" width="50" height="50" > </Label>
    <Label text="Label 2" width="50" height="50" > </Label>
    <Label text="Label 3" width="50" height="50" backgroundColor="white"> </Label>
    <Label text="Label 4" width="50" height="50" backgroundColor="white"> </Label>
  </StackLayout>
```

**component.css:**

```
StackLayout {
  margin: 10;
  background-color: green;

}

.stackBorder {
 border: 2px solid red;
   border-radius: 8px;
}
```

**component.ts:**

```
@Component({
    selector: "sdk-child-component",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./component.css"]
})
```

Finally I'm unable to see the border in stacklayout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In nativescript supported css properties are border-width, border-color and border-radius. Tag border alone is not possible nor any solid selection.

More info:

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling

Answer (score 10):

**Via html:**

```
<StackLayout borderRadius="30" borderColor="red" borderWidth="3"></StackLayout>
```

**Via css:**

```
StackLayout {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3;
  border-radius: 30;
}
```

More details: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#supported-css-properties

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use per-side borders. 
Check this
https://www.nativescript.org/blog/per-side-borders-in-nativescript-css